# phing - delete directory contents without directory itself

Tags: php, phing

I am trying to automate my PHP build, part of it is deleting selected content from a directory, as in below snippet

```xml
<delete verbose="${phing.verbose}">
    <fileset dir="${svn.exportDir}/includes" casesensitive="false">
        <exclude name="alerts.php"/>
        <exclude name="config.php"/>
        <exclude name="${client.name}_config.php"/>
        <exclude name="defaults.php"/>
        <exclude name="func.inc.php"/>
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

Now above code does remove includes folder as well, which is obviously undesirable. Phing does not understand

```
 dir="${svn.exportDir}/includes/**"
```

`(directory includes/** not found)`, and adding

```
<exclude name="${svn.exportDir}/includes"/>
```

to delete task is kind of awkward, so I was wondering whether there is a better way to remove selected content from directory with phing?

Answer (score 1):

it is a know bug, see http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/796
should be working with versions 2.9+

for me it currently does not work on 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried it myself and the same code would not delete the include folder. Only way to make it do so was to set the includeemptydirs to true. Maybe it's a version problem, but still, I would try calling it like this:

```xml
<delete includeemptydirs="false">
    <fileset dir="folder" casesensitive="false">
        <exclude name="excluded.php"/>
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

Comment: FYI: includeemptydirs="false" should be placed on delete tag, not fileset